# java replaceALL doesn't work (url whitespace to %20)

Tags: android, json, replaceall

My json file contains white space such as `1522663136Vehicle and Bike Procurement Notice 1.PDF`. In browswer, by default %20 is added. But while using this file in android project, I can't escape white space. My json output is as follow.

```
"heading": "Notice",
"content": "Tender Notice",
"img": "1522663136Vehicle and Bike Procurement Notice 1.PDF"
```

And I am trying to replace white space using `replaceALL`

```
String heading = hit.getString("heading");
String content = hit.getString("content");
String pdf = hit.getString("img");
pdf.replaceAll(" ","%20");
String link = "fitandfineindustries.com/images/notices/"+pdf;
mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(heading, date, content, click, link));
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: The answer by @jdigital is technically correct, but you may do better to just encode the entire URL using `URLEncoder#encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, strings are immutable, so replaceAll returns a new string rather than changing the existing one.  Try this:

```
pdf = pdf.replaceAll(" ","%20");
```

Comment: Thanks, I had forgot about it